# How to import a function from a different python file from another directory

Tags: python

PATH of `testFunc.py`: `Parent/test/testFunc.py`

PATH of `app.py`: `Parent/app.py`

`testFunc.py`:

```
def testRound(value):
        return int(value+0.5)

    

def isEligible(name, age):
        if age >= 18:
            return 'Hello '+name+', '+'you are eligible for driving'
        else:
            return 'Hello '+name+', '+'you are not eligible'
```

`app.py`:

```
from test.testFunc import *

print(isEligible('Shakya', 18))
print(testRound(4.5))
```

While executing `app.py`, it's showing `Error: > Module not found`.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: it needs (even empty) `test/__init__.py`

Answer (score 2):

Please put the blank `__init__.py` file in your `test` directory.

Your final file structure:

```
Parent
-- test
---- __init__.py
---- testFunc.py
-- app.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways

1. Add sys path to current directory, although IMO it's not recommended if you're going to do this in production, but if you plan to use it just for your use case go right ahead

> sys.path.append("")

> For your example it'd simply be

> sys.path.append("absolute path to Parent")

Add to your app.py code before importing test.testFunc

2. Relative import
   instead of importing

> from test.testFunc import *

do this

> from .test.testFunc import *

Either of these should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using sys module, you can simply add the directory to the sys.path list before importing the module.

So, your app.py script will be as below.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<path to subfolder>')

from testFunc import *

print(isEligible('Shakya', 18))
print(testRound(4.5))
```